# Does the request header (Accept) get persisted across requests?

Tags: jquery, request-headers

I am aware that a 'request' component should only be valid for the duration of that request. Thus my puzzling question.

Consider the following form:

```
<form action="${requestUri}" id="someform">
    <!-- Leave out some really boring stuff that doesn't affect the question -->
    <input type="submit" id="ButtonA" value="Button A - Not AJAX"/>
    <input type="submit" id="ButtonB" value="Button B - AJAX" />
</form>
```

It has the following jQuery attached to `ButtonB`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ButtonB").click(function(){
        var options = {
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                //Do some Work
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            }
        };
        $('#someform').ajaxForm(options);
    })
    }
</script>
```

In the event that I press `ButtonA` the form is submitted successfully and page reloaded. If I press `ButtonB` the AJAX command is executed successfully and the correct updates reflect on the page.

However. If I press `ButtonB` and then press `ButtonA`, the `Accept Header` for the second request is still sent through as `application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01` even though there is no 'JSON' action bound to this button.

Do I need to reset the `dataType` after completing the function?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Do you press `ButtonA` immediately after pressing `ButtonB`, or do you press it after the page reloads ?

Comment: The page does not reload after clicking `ButtonB`. It is initiating an `AJAX` request. `ButtonA` submits the page in its entirety.

Comment: But you are doing nothing to prevent the `default` action of `ButtonB`, so as far as I understand, your page should refresh, right?

Comment: use input type="button" or preventDefault event for ajax request

Comment: @SayemAhmed and @Scipion - My issue is not the AJAX call. It works as expected. My issue is that, once the AJAX call has completed, the subsequent click on a non-AJAX button still has the request-header set to `application/json`. I'm not sure if I need to 'reset' something. I've tried , `event.preventDefault()` (the AJAX also stops working) as well as `global: false` on the AJAX options (no impact) since posting.